# how to insert parent/child records simultaneously

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger that I want to insert parent (invoice) and child records (invoice lines) when an order reaches a status of complete. I have the bulk of the code written, but how can I grab the invoice id and populate into the invoice line during the insert? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
global class SalesOrderCreateInvoice implements ITriggers.HandlerInterface {

SalesOrder__c[] newCollection = trigger.new;

global void handle() {
    system.debug('************************** SalesOrderCreateInvoice START');
    if(!RecursionBlocker.salesOrderCreateInvoiceFirstCall) {
        system.debug('*********************** salesOrderCreateInvoiceFirstCall');
        createInvoices(getSalesOrderIds());
    }
    system.debug('************************** SalesOrderCreateInvoice END');     
}

private Set<Id> getSalesOrderIds() {
    Set<Id> retval = new Set<Id>();
    for(SalesOrder__c so : newCollection) {
        if(so.Status__c == 'Complete') {
            retval.add(so.Id);
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

private void createInvoices(Set<Id> salesOrderIds) {
    List<AcctSeed__Billing__c> invoicesToCreate = new List<AcctSeed__Billing__c>();
    List<AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c> invoiceLinesToCreate = new List<AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c>();
    if(!salesOrderIds.isEmpty() && salesOrderIds.size() > 0) {
        List<SalesOrder__c> salesOrdersToProcess = [Select Id, RecordType.Name, Account__c, Contact__c , Terms__c, OwnerId, 
                                                    (Select Id, Name, Sales_Order__c, Product_SKU__c, Product_SKU__r.AcctSeed__Revenue_GL_Account__c,
                                                    Product_SKU__r.AcctSeed__Expense_GL_Account__c, Quantity__c, Quantity_Packed__c, Price__c, 
                                                    Product_SKU__r.AcctSeed__Inventory_GL_Account__c, RecordType.Name From Sales_Order_Lines__r) From SalesOrder__c];
        for(SalesOrder__c so : salesOrdersToProcess) {
            AcctSeed__Billing__c invoice = new AcctSeed__Billing__c();
            invoice.Sales_Order__c = so.Id;
            invoice.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.AcctSeed__Billing__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(so.RecordType.Name).getRecordTypeId();
            invoice.AcctSeed__Date__c = system.today();
            invoice.AcctSeed__Customer__c = so.Account__c;
            invoice.Contact__c = so.Contact__c;
            invoice.Terms__c = so.Terms__c;
            invoice.Order_Owner__c = so.OwnerId;
            invoicesToCreate.add(invoice);
            for(Sales_Order_Line__c line : so.Sales_Order_Lines__r) {
                AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c invoiceLine = new AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c();
                invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Billing__c = // I need to populate the invoice id here!!;
                invoiceLine.Sales_Order_Line__c = line.Id;
                invoiceLine.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(line.RecordType.Name).getRecordTypeId();
                if(line.RecordType.Name == 'Blank Product') {
                    invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Hours_Units__c = Integer.valueOf(line.Quantity_Packed__c);
                }
                else {
                    invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Hours_Units__c = Integer.valueOf(line.Quantity__c);
                }
                invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Rate__c = line.Price__c;
                invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Product__c = line.Product_SKU__c;
                invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Revenue_GL_Account__c = line.Product_SKU__r.AcctSeed__Revenue_GL_Account__c;
                invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Expense_GL_Account__c = line.Product_SKU__r.AcctSeed__Expense_GL_Account__c;
                invoiceLine.AcctSeed__Inventory_GL_Account__c = line.Product_SKU__r.AcctSeed__Inventory_GL_Account__c;          
                invoiceLinesToCreate.add(invoiceLine);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!invoicesToCreate.isEmpty() && !invoiceLinesToCreate.isEmpty()) {        

        RecursionBlocker.salesOrderCreateInvoiceFirstCall = true;
        List<sObject> objectsToInsert = new List<sObject>();
        objectsToInsert.addAll((List<sObject>)(invoicesToCreate));
        objectsToInsert.addAll((List<sObject>)(invoiceLinesToCreate));
        insert objectsToInsert;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I literally posted code [about three days ago](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127275/how-can-i-insert-order-line-items-and-order-at-the-same-time/127278#127278) that demonstrates how to do this. Does this help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take an approach of using external id in the Parent (invoice) object. The sample code will look like this:

```
for(Sales_Order_Line__c line : so.Sales_Order_Lines__r) 
{
    AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c invoiceLine = new AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c(External_Id__c=invoice.External_Id__c);
    so.Sales_Order_Lines__r = invoiceLine;
    objectsToInsert.add(so);
}
    insert objectsToInsert;
```

Let me know if it is serving your purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you might have to use multiple for loops.

1. To  create invoice list that will be inserted. Insert them after first loop completion.
2. Creation of Map, Sales order Vs invoice id, this will be used to insert line items for invoices.
3. Again iterating over sales order , to create individual line items. The map you created earlier will be used here.

Comment: @Ratan, thanks for the response. Yeah, that would work. Ideally, I'd like to insert together instead of rolling back if there were issues in the invoice lines insertions. I don't want to create the invoice without the lines. I think there is a way to do this with external id. Trying to get that figured out if it is possible?